# apache poi , DataFormatter trimming values beyond ten places of decimal

Tags: java, apache-poi

So i have a simple code that populate values to database

```
try {
    for(int indexRow = 1; indexRow < numberOfRecords; indexRow++) {
        record = new String[noOfColumns];
        for(int indexColumn = 0;indexColumn < noOfColumns; indexColumn++) {
            indexError = indexColumn;
            String value = "";
            XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(indexRow);
            if(row != null) {
                XSSFCell cell = sheet.getRow(indexRow).getCell(indexColumn);

                if(cell != null) {
                    value = fmt.formatCellValue(cell);
                }
                record[indexColumn] = value;
            }
        }
        records.add(record);
    }
}
```

Now i have ran through the source code as well but i cannot find a way by which i can set the default DataFormatter in a way that it can change the DecimalFormat in a way to accomodate the extra changes .
Any help would be greatly appreciated .
Eg :in excel i have 
-5.57055337362326
but through code it writes into db as 
-5.5705533736

Answer (score 2):

**Important**: The purpose of the `DataFormatter.formatCellValue()` method is to return cell's value in the way it is shown in the *Excel* document.

Let's say if you will define numeric format in *Excel* to show 4 fractional digits and your document looks so:

[image: Excel, 4 fractional digits]

Your code sample will return `-5,5706`; if you will change numeric format to show 8 fractional digits - result will be `-5,57055337`.

By default numeric format in *Excel* is 10 digits based (in *Apache POI* please check `ExcelGeneralNumberFormat.decimalFormat` constant), and looks like it is the one used in your document based on the output you have.

---

### Solution

As it is mentioned by @samabcde (adding my answer to fix couple issues in his answer and to provide additional details), solution is to use `cell.getNumericCellValue()` instead:

```
    DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.###############");
    String cellValue = decimalFormat.format(cell.getNumericCellValue());
```

Here we've used `"#.###############"` format with 15 digits since it is a [maximum precision for Excel >>](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3)

---

### Additional information

1. Please pay attention to this article: [When reading Excel with POI, beware of floating points](https://blog.sourced-bvba.be/java/2013/08/22/when-reading-excel-with-poi-beware-of-floating-points/)
2. In terms of configuration of `DataFromatter` you can set up default number format using `DataFormatter#setDefaultNumberFormat(Format format)`, and it will be used when you call `format.formatCellValue(cell)`, but only in case of usage of unknown/broken formats in the *Excel* document.

---

### P.S.: Answer to the first comment

It is not fully clear from your comment all the cases you want to cover, assumption is that `DataFormatter` works for you in all cases except numeric values, and `DecimalFormat` with `"#.###############"` pattern works in that case for you. Anyway in case you will want more specific logic it will be needed just to check some other conditions.

Please find utility method you can use in this case:

```
private static final DecimalFormat DECIMAL_FORMAT = new DecimalFormat("#.###############");
private static final DataFormatter DATA_FORMATTER = new DataFormatter();

public static String formatCellValue(HSSFCell cell) {
    if (cell != null && cell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.NUMERIC
            && !DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
        return DECIMAL_FORMAT.format(cell.getNumericCellValue());
    } else {
        return DATA_FORMATTER.formatCellValue(cell);
    }
}
```

For the *Excel* file below:

[image: Different formats]

- Field *A1* has format of *4 fractional digits* with a real value `28,9999999999999`
- Field *A2* has format of *4 fractional digits* with a real value `-5.5`
- Field *A3* has default *Excel* format with a real value `28,9999999999999`

Utility method above will return real values here, i.e.: `28,9999999999999`, `-5.5` and `28,9999999999999`

`DataFormatter.formatCellValue()` will return values how they look in the *Excel* itself, i.e.: `29,0000`, `-5,5000` and `29`.

Comment: Hi , that does not solve my problem because the values are given in a way that can be whole numbers "0" or "0.00000" . 
With both the solutions i am getting undesired results . DataFoormatter seemed to solve my problem but for some reason they ended up adding a limitation of only ten digits and also made the property as final , private and static .It is so frustrating to find this limitation right now .
What i want is text to remain as text , whole numbers to remain as whole numbers and decimals being decimals . Sometimes i have seen the cell value taking 0 as 1.00 as 1.0000000009

Comment: @user1150082, there is a link in the __Additional information__ section to handle numbers correctly, it is because of internal handling if `double` in _Java_, please read it too.

Comment: @user1150082, what relates to handling dates, strings and numbers using single call - you will need then to introduce utility method by taking into account cell type by comparing it to `CellType` enum. I'm currently not on my working place, will check it a bit later. But answer is a correct one :)

Comment: @user1150082, please find utility method you can use in your case (adjusted my answer, please see P.S. section). And please let me add once again: the purpose of the `DataFormatter` is not accuracy, but to return cell values in the way they look in the _Excel_ itself, i.e. using their style/format from the document - you can't override its logic and this is why all it's defined formats are final/private/static.

Comment: I'll check it up as soon as possible .

Comment: Hi , i tried your above code and thank you for the help but it ends up failing . Your code is somewhat similar to the one i used , now i think that it's more of an api issue than logic . You see i am using an excel in which there are two values 7 and 2 .
It reads 7 as 7.0000000009 and 2 as 2 . This is the reason i used Dataformatter , even in your code it fails that test for some unknown reason .

Comment: @user1150082, please provide me the *Excel* file to reproduce your issue, but please check it first on your side - I assume you don't want to send me real data, but a cut version, so please don't send me just an Excel with two cells filled with `2` and `7` without testing it :)

Comment: @user1150082, and let me please know version of _Apache POI_ you are using.

Comment: @user1150082, also try next version please: in `formatCellValue()` utility method above replace `return DECIMAL_FORMAT.format(cell.getNumericCellValue());` part with `cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING); return cell.getStringCellValue();`

Answer (score 0):

### Reason for losing digit

The below code is from POI version 3.14, for the `DataFormatter.formatCellValue` method, with numeric cell, it will eventually call `getFormattedNumberString` method. The code is as

```
private String getFormattedNumberString(Cell cell, ConditionalFormattingEvaluator 
    cfEvaluator) {

    Format numberFormat = getFormat(cell, cfEvaluator);
    double d = cell.getNumericCellValue();
    if (numberFormat == null) {
        return String.valueOf(d);
    }
    String formatted = numberFormat.format(new Double(d));
    return formatted.replaceFirst("E(\\d)", "E+$1"); // to match Excel's E-notation
}
```

The `numberFormat` will be a `DecimalFormat` with 10 decimal places by default, suppose you have not set any format, a cell with value '-5.57055337362326' will return '-5.5705533736' as expected.

### Solution

If only the exact value is needed, using `cell.getNumericValue` method and create a `DecimalFormat` can solve this problem. If the display in Excel is required to change also, then we need to created a custom `DataFormatter`. Both solutions are illustrated in following example:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormat;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class TestDataFormatter {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Double testValue = Double.valueOf("-5.57055337362326");
        System.out.println("test value:\t\t" + testValue.toString());
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
        Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
        Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
        cell.setCellValue(testValue);

        // 10 decimal place shown by default 
        DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();
        String defaultFormatted = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell);
        System.out.println("default formatted:\t" + defaultFormatted);

        // Create custom format
        XSSFCellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
        DataFormat customDataFormat = workbook.createDataFormat();
        int dataFormatIndex = customDataFormat.getFormat("0.00000000000000");
        style.setDataFormat(dataFormatIndex);
        cell.setCellStyle(style);
        String customFormatted = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell);
        System.out.println("custom formatted:\t" + customFormatted);

        // Get numeric value and then format by DecimalFormat
        System.out.println("get numeric:\t\t" + cell.getNumericCellValue());
        System.out.println(
                "format numeric:\t\t" + new DecimalFormat("0.00000000000000").format(cell.getNumericCellValue()));
        workbook.close();
    }
}
```